# Не отображается изображение в IE9

Tags: canvas, javascript, internet-explorer, html5

У меня есть canvas. На нем отлично рисуются графические примитивы, но почему-то вставка изображения не всегда работает хорошо. Использую метод:

```
e.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

В Мозиле и в Хроме всё работает нормально, но в IE9 периодически падает ошибка:

```
 DOM Exception: INDEX_SIZE_ERR (1)
 code: 1  ABORT_ERR: 20 
 DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2 
 HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3 
 INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1 
 INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10 
 INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15 
 INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5 
 INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13 
 INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11 
 NAMESPACE_ERR: 14  
 NETWORK_ERR: 19  
 NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8 
 NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9 
 NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6 
 NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7 
 PARSE_ERR: 81  
 QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22 
 SECURITY_ERR: 18  
 SERIALIZE_ERR: 82 
 SYNTAX_ERR: 12  
 TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17 
 URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21  
 VALIDATION_ERR: 16  
 WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Судя по всему ошибку случается не при выполнении drawImage, а где-то ещё. Локализуйте место ошибки точнее.

Comment: Я добавлял отладочный вывод и он показал, что приложение падает именно на этой строчке. При этом в этой строке нет никаких вычислений или создания/получения картинки, и т.д.

Comment: Там действительно были нули. Но теперь непонятно, почему приходит event о загрузке изображения, а размер 0*0 (в других браузерах нормальный размер). Из-за чего такое может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А у вас все переменные больше нуля? Может падать из-за этого.